# MongoDB count most common nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection of poems. The document in the collection has the following structure:

```
{
"_id" : "Romeo and Juliet",
"acts" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "ACT I",
        "scenes" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "SCENE I. Verona. A public place.",
                "action" : [ 
                    {
                        "character" : "SAMPSON",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "Gregory, o' my word, we'll not carry coals."
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "character" : "GREGORY",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "No, for then we should be colliers."
                        ]
                    }, 
                    // ...
                    {
                        "character" : "GREGORY",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "To move is to stir; and to be valiant is to stand:", 
                            "therefore, if thou art moved, thou runn'st away."
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "character" : "SAMPSON",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "A dog of that house shall move me to stand: I will", 
                            "take the wall of any man or maid of Montague's."
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "character" : "GREGORY",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "That shows thee a weak slave; for the weakest goes", 
                            "to the wall."
                        ]
                    }, 
                    // ...
            },
            // ...
        ]
    },
    // ...
]}
```

I need to find the poem with the most number of dialog (`says`) in the `scene` object.
I have tried use the `$group`, `$unwind`, `$sort`, and etc, but the result is not really correct.

Comment: Could you post your aggregation code and we'll see where you are going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find the poem with the most number of dialog (says) in the
>   scene object

This can be interpreted in the following way.

> Count all says across all action in all scenes object for all acts in each poem and show
>   the poem document which has the max says across
>   all poems.

The idea is to found the max says across all actions, all scenes and all acts and output the poem document with max says.

Nested `$map` and `$max` combination to output the max values across different levels.

`$project` with exclusion to drop the "maxsaysacrossallacts" field.

Something like

```
 db.poems.aggregate([
  {"$addFields":{
    "maxsaysacrossallacts":{
      "$max":{
        "$map":{
          "input":"$acts",
          "as":"maxsaysineachact",
          "in":{
            "$max":{
              "$map":{
                "input":"$$maxsaysineachact.scenes",
                "as":"maxsaysineachscene",
                "in":{
                  "$max":{
                    "$map":{
                      "input":"$$maxsaysineachscene.action",
                      "as":"sayssceneineachaction",
                      "in":{"$size":"$$sayssceneineachaction.says"}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$sort":{"maxsaysacrossallacts":-1}},
  {"$limit":1},
  {"$project":{"maxsaysacrossallacts":0}}
])
```

**Update:** Based on the comment below if you require to output max says poem document you can use below aggregation query.

Count all the says across all acts and output the poem with max say count.

```
db.poems.aggregate([
  {"$addFields":{
    "sumsaysacrossallacts":{
      "$sum":{
        "$map":{
          "input":"$acts",
          "as":"sumsaysineachact",
          "in":{
            "$sum":{
              "$map":{
                "input":"$$sumsaysineachact.scenes",
                "as":"sumsaysineachscene",
                "in":{
                  "$sum":{
                    "$map":{
                      "input":"$$sumsaysineachscene.action",
                      "as":"sayssceneineachaction",
                      "in":{"$size":"$$sayssceneineachaction.says"}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$sort":{"sumsaysacrossallacts":-1}},
  {"$limit":1},
  {"$project":{"sumsaysacrossallacts":0}}
])
```

Comment: we need to use `$reduce` to sum all the says, max will not yield correct result

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure if OP wants the max of sum just max say in poem. Updated post to include sum for max.

Answer (score 1):

can you try below aggregation, we are flattening acts, then scenes, then action and finally says to get the total count of dialogues, `$sort` to order poems by total count

```
db.poems.aggregate(
    [
        {$addFields : {flatActs : {$reduce : {input : "$acts", initialValue : [], in : {$concatArrays : ["$$value", ["$$this"]]}}}}},
        {$addFields : {flatScenes : {$reduce : {input : "$flatActs.scenes", initialValue : [], in : {$concatArrays : ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}},
        {$addFields : {flatAction : {$reduce : {input : "$flatScenes.action", initialValue : [], in : {$concatArrays : ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}},
        {$addFields : {flatSays : {$reduce : {input : "$flatAction.says", initialValue : [], in : {$concatArrays : ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}},
        {$addFields : {dialogCount : {$size : "$flatSays"}}},
        {$sort : {dialogCount : -1}},
        {$project : {flatActs : 0, flatScenes : 0, flatAction : 0, flatSays : 0}}
    ]
).pretty()
```